# How can I get JSON data and parse it to an Array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get Data from a server and parse it so I can format it into something to display in HTML

I'm getting issues with Parsing the data from the JSON file

Here's my code:

JS

```js
    var AnnouncementsJSON
    $.get("data/announcements.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        AnnouncementsJSON = $.parseJSON(data)
    });
    console.log(AnnouncementsJSON)
```

announcements.json

```json
    {
    "announcements":[
        {
            "title":"This is the Announcement!",
            "subtitle":"This is going to be used as announcements",
            "link":"/somewhere.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Console/Inspect Element:

```
(index):189 {announcements: Array(1)}
VM976:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success ((index):190)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):190
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
l @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
S.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):188
```

Above the Error message, it shows `{Announcements: Array(1)}`, so I know I can access the JSON file from the browser. Plus I navigated to it and I was able to access it

Comment: "Unexpected token o" almost _always_ means  you're not getting JSON at all: open your dev tools, select the network tab, rerun your fetch and look at what you're _actually_ getting back.

Comment: "Unexpected token o" typically arises when you attempt to parse something that has already been parsed. Log `typeof data` and if it's "object", jQuery has already parsed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution you are looking for is [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), but I also see this payload as not needing JSON.parse because it comes in as an object. [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) returns an object with the response payload.

Comment: I think you are correct because I see the same error when I try this example: 
var e = JSON.parse({thing:"test"})
That example parse an object but it gives an error, because it should be parsing the JSON string.

Comment: In other words, can just do : AnnouncementsJSON = data;

Comment: @raddevus you're correct! JSON.parse expects a stringified object so it can turn it into an object. Counter to that is JSON.stringify which takes an object and turns it into a string. It is very useful for storing encrypted objects in local storage.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access it without any additional parsing. I think you are getting that error because you are trying to parse already parsed json...